# Share Intent in Service Class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have `Service` in my application with share button that opens Share intent:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
dialogIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
dialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

dialogIntent.setType("text/plain");
dialogIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ytf.getTitle());
startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

It's called from my Service class and I get this `Exception`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.services.BackgroundPlayerService@95236fd with Intent { cmp=com.dev/com.services.BackgroundPlayerService launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] typ=text/plain flg=0x10000001 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } clip={text/plain T:Watch "CHVRCHES - Get Out (Preview)"
```

Any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea where is the problem?

Remove this line:

```
dialogIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Comment: the app now not crashing, but the share is on the activity and not in the service

Comment: @MTA: "but the share is on the activity and not in the service" -- I do not know what that means, sorry.